# Гугл поиск на Python

Tags: python, поиск, браузер, webbrowser

Нужно просто, чтобы программа открывала гугл и писала в него , то что необходимо найти.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как вариант. На время печатания блокирует клавиатуру и мышь, чтобы не сломать скрипт. В случае медленного интернета можно увеличить время в `time.sleep`.

```
import keyboard
import time
import webbrowser
from ctypes import *

a = ('Поисковый запрос')

def printText():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('www.google.com')
    windll.user32.BlockInput(True)
    time.sleep(2)
    c = len(a)
    b = 0
    while b < c:
        keyboard.write(a[b])
        time.sleep(0.1)
        b = b + 1
        keyboard.press_and_release('return')
    windll.user32.BlockInput(False)

printText()
```